# Apache Airflow ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_linux'

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, importerror, psutil

I am installing apache airflow as per the installation steps provided at https://airflow.apache.org/start.html#quick-start

1. First Step - `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow` (No error)
2. Second Step - `pip install apache-airflow` (No error)
3. Third Step - `airflow initdb` ( Error - `ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_linux'`)

Detailed of error is shown in below image:

[image]

Environment detail is as below-

- Python Version - Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (32-bit)
- Pip Version - 10.0.1
- Ubuntu Version - 14.04 LTS
- OS Type - 32 bits

How should I go on resolving it? I have already tried updating pip and installing python-dev but that does not work.

Comment: I had same problem in Ubuntu 16.04 with other python code. It turns out the problem is python 3.7. When I ran the code with pyton 3.5 the problem solved.

Answer (score 10):

I've overcome this problem through the following command:

```
pip install -U --ignore-installed psutil
```

---

This works if you have installed `psutil` by `pip`, otherwise, try via `apt` in Ubuntu:

```
apt-get update
apt-get --only-upgrade install python-psutil
apt-get install python-psutil
```

Comment: psutil package is not recognised by apt-get

Answer (score 3):

installing `python-dev` will do the job

if you are running ubuntu then `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

or simply running `pip install -U psutil` should do the job.

Comment: installing python-dev does not help as it states that it is already the newest version. Error remains as it is even after running above commands.